# How do I count the number of unique rows in group by laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three notifications type, `TYPE_A` `TYPE_B` `TYPE_C`. For each type there could be multiple notifications for a single user. I want to get the number of notifications a user got for each of the notification types.
For now I have this:

```
$notifications = Notification::where('user_id', $user->id)->groupBy('notification_type')->get();
```

How do I count the number of rows each `notification_type` has?

Comment: so you want to count the rows that have unique `notification_type`?

Comment: `->count()` probably. https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Comment: @NewbeeDev yep. unique notification type for each user. For example how many of `TYPE_A` notifications have `user_1` got

Comment: hi there can you put a sample data and your desired output for more explaination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `raw()` method as:

```
$notifications = Notification::where('user_id', $user->id)
            ->select('*', DB::raw("count(*) as count"))
            ->groupBy('notification_type')
            ->get();
```